# Drag/Drop 4K video files from Photos app to FCPX results in 1080p resolution video file

Tags: 4k

When I drag and drop 4K video files that are over a certain size (approx > 140MB) from my Photos App/iCloud library in MacOS (Ventura), to the Final Cut Pro X program, the resulting video file is reduced (automatically) to a 1080p resolution file.  This never happened before I changed the option in the Photos app to "Optimize Mac Storage", from "Download Originals to this Mac".  I have a 2TB video library and I ran out of disk space.  I can still download 1080p content without any issue, but not the 4K content, if it's over about 45 seconds in video length.  I can drag and drop these files to the Desktop or an other local folder on the drive, and it drops the full resolution 4K video file.  I can actually drag that file from the desktop into FCPX and it will give me a full 4K resolution video file also.  It only reduces the video clips when drag/drop directly from the Photos app into FCPX.  Anybody have an idea what might be going on here?  Any thoughts would be appreciated.